# cfengine: No access to workspace

Tags: cfengine

I'm completely new to Cfengine and I've just installed it on my Debian system. But when I try to invoke any of its executables as a non-privileged user, here is what I always get:

```
$ /usr/sbin/cf-key 
Fatal cfengine error:  !!! No access to workspace
```

Strangely enough, it looks like my local workspace got correctly created:

```
$ tree .cfagent/
.cfagent/
|-- bin
|-- lastseen
|-- outputs
`-- reports
```

So any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Googling for this error message drew a blank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the inputs directory.
Doing mkdir ~/.cfagent/inputs should do the trick.